# Does a web page continue to run JavaScript after starting a navigation?

Tags: javascript

I believe I am observing the following browser behavior:

1. The page initiates a navigation (via `<meta http-equiv='refresh'>`)
2. The navigation goes through a series of redirections
3. Before the redirections complete, a timer on the original page fires,
   initiating another navigation (via `window.location.href`)
4. The second navigation cancels the first

However, my searches on Google and StackOverflow don't find anyone describing a similar behavior. Can anyone tell me (or preferably point me to an authoritative source) if my theory is correct: that a page continues to run JavaScript even after a navigation, as long as that navigation has not resolved to a landing page yet?

Comment: Have you tried setting `content` attribute as in here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html Also as soon as there is redirect passed to browser your page will stop interacting/executing.

Comment: @Justinas that seems likely to stop the JavaScript, but I don't want to stop it. I don't own the page, and I'd guess the JavaScript timer is specifically present to provide an error fallback if the redirection takes too long. So this isn't a problem I need to solve - I'm just curious if this is expected/documented behavior. I haven't run across it before.

Comment: Can you add some console statements in a `beforeunload` and `unload` event listener?  See if you are able to kill the timer as well.  It's going to be difficult to help debug this since we don't have a reproducible example (and one would be difficult to provide).

Answer (score 0):

Add the content attribute to block javascript https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://redirect.com'" />
```

this should stop further script execution. Also the timeout should be set to 0, I believe scripts will continue to execute before the timeout period.

check out the

```js
window.beforeunload 

window.onunload
```

methods for debugging. You'll need to have a way in your JS code to interrupt the timer.

in general redirects should be done server side where possible, using the meta refresh fails WCAG's guidelines. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Comment: Thanks for the details; however, I'm not interested in stopping the javascript - as far as I can tell, it plays a legitimate role for error-handling, when the redirection takes too long. I'm more curious if this behavior (where the javascript of the old page keeps running, while the redirection is in-progress) is a standard I can rely on, or is it browser-specific behavior?

Comment: I believe it is standard behavior you can rely on in every browser, but I haven't got any reference material to give.